# How to generate a personal access token like github?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, identityserver4

This is theoretical question.

I want to create mechanism alike Github 'personal access tokens' in .net core webapi which already has 'ResourceOwnerPassword' flow with Identity Server 4.

In theory i want to manually generate a token upon user request, store it and then create a custom AutorizeFilter which will take it into account. In example i will look into authorization header and if Bearer proceed to base AutorizeFilter and if that Basic then check storage for the token and 'authorize differently without authentication'.

1. Is is this flow seems like a common pattern or I am off ?
2. How to 'authorize differently without authentication' ? I means can i just send Authorization: token xxxxxx and avoid Authentication.

Sorry for odd question, i just don't know how to ask that other way around.

Comment: Your second question is not very clear.

Comment: @Evk, thanks. Is it better now ?

Comment: using ResourceOwnerPassword will allow you to authecate with a user name and password.  it will require a PasswordValidator on your identtiy server to work though.

Comment: @DaImTo, this flow already works. I want to add another flow access with personal token instead of user/password to work along with ResourceOwnerPassword

Comment: I think your looking for something like what twitter does its an oauth1 type solution.   I have been trying to track down how to get that working as well the closest i have been able to come is resourceownerpassword.

Comment: You certainly can do that. Just inherit from AuthorizeAttribute (or FilterAttribute) and override `AuthorizeCore` to perform your custom check.

Comment: @Evk what i did so far was implementing multiple policy handlers instead of overriding AuthorizeFilter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#security-authorization-policies-based-handler-registration

Comment: Well if it works then it works. But if you have working solution, what is the question then? :)

Comment: @Evk, 1. to know if i have solution right. 2. i was looking for solution during the chat with you guys here. don't we all ?